# Sails.js app can't see index.ejs?

Tags: node.js, model-view-controller, sails.js

Going through a nettuts tutorial on sails.js and am having problems displaying my index.ejs file. I created the index.ejs file under `views\main\`, but when I run the app with `sails lift` it's saying:

```
{
  "status": 500,
  "errors": [
    "Failed to lookup view \"main/index\""
  ]
}
```

in the browser. I checked several time and everything appears to be named correctly and placed in the correct directories. I'm using node.js v0.10.20 and sails v0.9.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is an issue for Sails 0.9.7... [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/983)

For now I think you could revert back to 0.9.4

```
npm remove sails -g
npm cache clear
npm install sails@0.9.4 -g
```

Comment: I have a problem reverting back to 0.9.4... It throws an error saying about npm-cache.. Please help..

Answer (score 3):

Open this file in a text editor

C:\Documents and Settings\\Application Data\npm\node_modules\sails\lib\express\views.js

in line 10 change as below

```
//return glob.sync(path, {nocase: true});

return glob.sync(basename (path), {cwd: dirname (path), nocase: true});
```

in line 28

```
//if (exists(path)) return globPath(path)[0];

if (exists (path)) return path;
```

in line 33

```
//if (exists(path)) return globPath(path)[0];

if (exists (path)) return path;
```

Comment: It worked for me. Thank you. 
Note: Did not try Melvin's answer.